# Finding parametric equations for the curved path of a particle around a half-circle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a question about parametric equations. So far I've learned how to find the parametric equations for a straight line, I know about replacing $x^2$ and $y^2$ in the equation of the unit circle, but I'm having trouble with this particular problem.

Note that this seems to be a popular problem, there are solutions to it plastered over the Internet, including on StackExchange, but the explanations are not in-depth enough for a newbie of my calibre of the process behind these solutions, that's what I'm struggling with. The question is as follows:

“Find parametric equations for the path of a particle that moves
halfway around the circle $x2 + (y – 1)2 = 4$ counter-clockwise, starting at the point (0 , 3).”

Here is a screenshot of the graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUX7V.png

Could somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 4):

A generic circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin is given parametrically by $\alpha(t) = \langle r\cos(t), r\sin(t) \rangle$ such that $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. This is pretty straightforward.  Simply draw a circle centered at the origin and draw a line segment from its center to an arbitrary point on its perimeter.  Call the angle the segment makes with the $x$-axis $t$.  Then, simply think about how $\sin$ and $\cos$ are defined geometrically in terms of a right triangle.  It follows immediately that the $y$-coordinate of your point will be given by $r\sin(t)$, and the $x$-coordinate of your point will be given by $r\cos(t)$.

You can then translate the circle as many units as you'd like in the $x$ or $y$ direction by adding the appropriate number of units to either the $x$ or the $y$ component of the parametrization.  I.e. $\alpha(t) = \langle x + r\cos(t), y + r\sin(t) \rangle$.

Once you have a parameterization for the entire circle centered at the point you'd like, think about what values of $t$ that yield only the half you want.  (Remember that $t$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and a segment from an arbitrary point on your half-circle to the origin).

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I don't know trig as much as I thought--I really am trying to understand this concept. So I figure I need to use sin(pi/2) and cos(pi/2) and restrict their domain so they only follow through half the circle...but can you explain the process a little more?

Comment: No no, you're on the right track.  For the full circle, $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.  For the half circle, we just need to find an appropriate restriction on the domain.  $t$ would definitely need to start at $\pi/2$.  This is because the line segment from the origin to the top of the circle makes an angle of $\pi/2$ with the $x$-axis.  Now where would it need to end?

Comment: Well, I guess it wouldn't be "from the origin" any more once it's been translated, but from its center is what I mean.

Comment: The domain would be pi/2 <= t <= (3pi)/2, if I am understanding this right then x would equal 2cos(t) and y would equal 2sin(t) + 1, at least I think the plus 1 goes to the y coordinate, or is it minus 1? I'm also still confused about the direction of the curve, am I on the right path still?

Comment: That is precisely correct.  It would be $+1$ since you are adding $1$ unit to the $y$-coordinate.  That is one of the beautiful things about parameterizations: you don't have to play the game of whether $+1$ shifts it left/right or up/down as you do with some explicit formulae.  It always does what you would expect.

Comment: Also, the parameterization will trace out the circle in a counterclockwise manner since an increasing angle $t$ means you are "moving away" from the positive $x$-axis (for the lack of a better description).