# Find the parametric equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the parametric equations from the following curves
A. The line segment from $P=(9,8,5)$ to $Q=(13,-2,0)$
B. $x^2+y^2=9$ for only positive $x$ values.

I could not even get to the starting point from part A 
but from what I know that i have to find $PQ$ but I'm not sure about it

Comment: So tell us what PQ is and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints

**A**

The general parametric equation for a line passing through two points $P$ and $Q$ is given by:
$$\boxed{\vec r=\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=P+\lambda(Q-P)}$$

(where $P$ and $Q$ are in vector-form).

**B**

The general parametric equation of a circle through the origin is given by:
$$\boxed{(x,y)=(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))},$$ where the Cartesian of the circle is $x^2+y^2=r^2.$

Comment: what do you mean by λ ???

Comment: $\lambda$ is a number. I could have said $t$ or $\mu$ or $a$; it's just some constant.

Comment: In your answer, leave $\lambda$ (and $t$ in the second part) in your answer.

Comment: and for part B I got this answer (3cost,3sint) so is there a value for t ?

Comment: $t$ is just a number, like $\lambda$, so leave $t$ in your answer. You're pretty much right. Just need to put $(x,y)=(3\cos(t),3\sin(t))$.

Answer (score 1):

Line segments can always be parametrized in the form $\alpha(t) = (v_2 - v_1)t + v_1$.

The usual trick is letting $t$ range $0 \leq t \leq 1$.  At time $t = 0$, we want to be at our starting point $P$.  So in our general form above, we know $P = v_1$.

Next, we want to be at point $Q$ when $t = 1$.  To do this, simply let $v_2 = Q$.  Hence, when $t = 1$, the $v_1$'s will cancel.

---

To answer your second question, see my thorough explanation from another thread:

[Finding parametric equations for the curved path of a particle around a half-circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836644/finding-parametric-equations-for-the-curved-path-of-a-particle-around-a-half-cir/836648#836648)